# Typescript expressions not evaluating in Angular 8 Router on production build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I am trying to execute a TS expression inside the router module of my angular app. I want to evaluate the following expression, `const check: any = window.innerWidth > 600 ? RouteOneComponent : RouteTwoComponent;`

But it always routes to the `RouteOneComponent`, even when the `window.innerWidth` value is less than 600

I created simple application to reproduce this behavior, and following is my router module code

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouteOneComponent } from "./route-one/route-one.component";
import { RouteTwoComponent } from "./route-two/route-two.component";

const check: any = window.innerWidth > 600 ? RouteOneComponent : RouteTwoComponent;

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'web', component: RouteOneComponent },
  { path: 'mob', component: RouteTwoComponent },
  //tried this - didn't work after build
  { path: 'check', component: window.innerWidth > 600 ? RouteOneComponent : RouteTwoComponent }
  //also tried this - didn't work after build
  { path: 'check', component: check }
  //also tried this - didn't work after build
  { path: 'check', component: (() => {return window.innerWidth > 600 ? RouteOneComponent : RouteTwoComponent})() }
  //also tried removing the above anonymous function to a named function
  //gave error during template compile, function calls not supported in decorators
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I compile and run on my local it works mine, when I build (`ng build --prod=true`) and run the application and then go to `localhost:4200/check`, the expression fallbacks to being true and always opens the `RouteOneComponent` even on mobile.

Is there any TS configuration (`ts-config.json`) that results in such behaviour? What is the approach to debug the issue or fix it, this only happens after build but not in local.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is you can first redirect to a common component and in that attached compoenent template use ng-if to enable the appropiate compoenent view.

Something like this

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <router-one-component *ngIf="isWindowsSizeMorethan600"></router-one-component>
        <router-two-component *ngIf="!isWindowsSizeMorethan600"></router-two-component>
    `

isWindowsSizeMorethan600: boolean;    
ngOnInit() {        
        this.isWindowsSizeMorethan600 = window.innerWidth > 600;
}
```

Other option is to use dynamic compoenent loading option. In that case you have to use `ViewContainerRef` to get the reference to a container and dynamically load compoenent with `createComponent` method.

See the example below

```
template: `
    <ng-template #vc></ng-template>
  `

@ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    loadComponent(vc);
}

async loadComponent(vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    const { RouteOneComponent } = await import('./somepath/route-one.component');
    const { RouteTwoComponent } = await import('./somepath/route-two.component');

    vcr.clear();
    let component : any = window.innerWidth > 600 ? RouteOneComponent : RouteTwoComponent ;       
    return vcr.createComponent(
      this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(component))    
}}
```

You can find the complete reference in doc https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: I agree to your approach. But I can't create extra components in my actual project. I am looking for a way to evaluate the TS expression in route module.
Also curious about, why this works on local compile and run but not on Prod builds. Any ts-config flags I am missing out??

Comment: I am afraid what you are trying to do directly in approuting compoenent might not be supported, if you can create a `authguard service` with `canActivate` attrib then you can switch compoenents from there also. This will eliminate the concern of creating a separate compoenent as you are not inclined on that direction.